# Combination of few list with keeping order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a few lists that I want to make combinations the output should have the first item from list1 second from list2 and last from list3.

I tried with for and append but it did not work can itertools be used?

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
list3 = [7, 8 ,9]
```

Output should be

```py
[[1,4,7],[2,4,7]...[3,6,9]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried with for and append but it did not work" ? What have you tried so far? Show us your attempts so far

Comment: `import itertools as it` and `for pr in it.product(list1, list2,list3):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try considering simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). What makes your question unique is the order of elements. The key point here is to have `list1` as the inner most loop **just** to have the output in the order you want.

```
result = [[i, j, k] for k in list3 for j in list2 for i in list1]
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 4, 7],
 [2, 4, 7],
 [3, 4, 7],
 [1, 5, 7],
 [2, 5, 7],
 [3, 5, 7],
 [1, 6, 7],
 [2, 6, 7],
 [3, 6, 7],
 [1, 4, 8],
 [2, 4, 8],
 [3, 4, 8],
 [1, 5, 8],
 [2, 5, 8],
 [3, 5, 8],
 [1, 6, 8],
 [2, 6, 8],
 [3, 6, 8],
 [1, 4, 9],
 [2, 4, 9],
 [3, 4, 9],
 [1, 5, 9],
 [2, 5, 9],
 [3, 5, 9],
 [1, 6, 9],
 [2, 6, 9],
 [3, 6, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy`

```
print([list(x) for x in numpy.array(numpy.meshgrid(list1,list2,list3)).T.reshape(-1,len(a))])
```

Outputs:

```
[[1, 4, 7], [1, 5, 7], [1, 6, 7], [2, 4, 7], [2, 5, 7], [2, 6, 7], [3, 4, 7], [3, 5, 7], [3, 6, 7], [1, 4, 8], [1, 5, 8], [1, 6, 8], [2, 4, 8], [2, 5, 8], [2, 6, 8], [3, 4, 8], [3, 5, 8], [3, 6, 8], [1, 4, 9], [1, 5, 9], [1, 6, 9], [2, 4, 9], [2, 5, 9], [2, 6, 9], [3, 4, 9], [3, 5, 9], [3, 6, 9]]
```